# 2 usb cameras not working with opencv

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I'm working on a project of computer vision and I need to use two cameras using opencv library. I tried this code but with two webcams from USB port it doesn't work while it works if I use one usb camera and the camera of my pc.

```
CvCapture* capture[2];                      

capture[0] = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
capture[1] = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);

if(!capture[0] && !capture[1])
    printf("Webcam error\n");
```

I'm working on windows 7 on an acer aspire 5742g. Is it a problem of the bus of my computer? The cameras are 2 Philips SPZ2000.
I tried also to work on the pictures taken by the one of them and from the camera on my pc and when I use the code for calibration and rectification found on the book "Learning opencv" of Bradsky I get a bad result. Can somebody help me?
Thank you in advance,

Sara

Answer (score 11):

The typical reason for 2+ USB cameras to not work together (still they might be working fine separately) is that USB bandwidth is insufficient for them both to run simultaneously. There is a bandwidth limit, which is rather low: [The maximum throughput of an isochronous pipe (which is usually used for video) is 24MB/s](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/b4c0703a-ac2a-4c70-91d0-7e3897eb4a88/).

More on this issue:

- [Implications of using many USB web cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519057/implications-of-using-many-usb-web-cameras)
- [How many USB cameras can be accessed by one PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239843/how-many-usb-cameras-can-be-accessed-by-one-pc)
- [Not able to capture video using 2 webcamera simulteneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264846/not-able-to-capture-video-using-2-webcamera-simulteneously)
- [Two webcams on one usb hub - bandwidth issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664605/two-webcams-on-one-usb-hub-bandwidth-issues)

Comment: If the two cameras are connected to two different root hubs it works.

Comment: @WoJo "*two different root hubs*" means that there are two USB host controllers, and each camera has its own USB bus.