# Raspberry Pi 4 8GB - 2 USB Cams - C++ not loading but JS loads video in browser

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture, webcam-capture

I have Raspberry pi 4 with 8GB ram, I have connected two USB webcams (Eternico Webcam ET101 HD) to it, I need to read video from both cameras at once for triangulation of detected objects.

I am using C++ code from OpenCV docs: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat frame;
    //--- INITIALIZE VIDEOCAPTURE
    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera using default API
    // cap.open(0);
    // OR advance usage: select any API backend
    int deviceID = 0;             // 0 = open default camera
    int apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;      // 0 = autodetect default API
    // open selected camera using selected API
    cap.open(deviceID, apiID);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    cout << "Start grabbing" << endl
        << "Press any key to terminate" << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        cap.read(frame);
        // check if we succeeded
        if (frame.empty()) {
            cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        imshow("Live", frame);
        if (waitKey(5) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem** is when I try to load video from both cameras at once, whole video stream just frezzes and I have to kill it.

I tried to use python code for OpenCV, but with same behaviour.

I ran it as separate processes, just with different deviceID -> **not working** (The first camera opens correctly, when the second tries to open it freezes and I have to kill it)

I also tried it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13926879/17053282 -> **not working -** same as above

After searching for answers I found out that problem could be related to USB bandwidth, but.. Interesting is that when I tried to load video using **JS in web browser it** **works perfectly fine**. Screen below..

[Live video from both cameras displayed in webrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otee4.png)

Any ideas what could be wrong? Or how to run it in C++?

**Goal:** I need to read video from cameras simultaneously, and stream it over network in C++.

Comment: attempt to reproduce this with something other than opencv. use guvcview or ffmpeg or whatever.

Comment: Did you try specifying the backend (`apiID`) explicitly, rather than depending on auto-detection? | What backend does it actually use when auto-detecting? | Also, if you just need to stream the video from a camera, do you really need to write your own program using OpenCV, as opposed to just using some existing solution?