# Opencv capture video from multiple cameras

Tags: c++, opencv

I am verifying multiple video captures by Opencv 3.4, there are 3 cameras in use, one built-in camera in the laptop and 2 USB cameras connected two separated USB ports. I can't make the video captures happen, it always throws exception as:

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /opt/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 890
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer(CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_V4L2, reinterpret_cast<char *>(index))): raised OpenCV exception:

/opt/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:890: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer

libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /opt/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 890
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer(CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_V4L2, reinterpret_cast<char *>(index))): raised OpenCV exception:

/opt/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:890: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer

cap1 doesn't work
```

Source code is quite simple:

```
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap0(0); // open the default camera
    VideoCapture cap1(1);
    VideoCapture cap2(2);
    if(!cap0.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "cap0 doesn't work" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if(!cap1.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "cap1 doesn't work" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if(!cap2.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "cap2 doesn't work" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat frame0;
    Mat frame1;
    Mat frame2;
    for(;;)
    {

        cap0 >> frame0; // get a new frame from camera
        cap1 >> frame1;
        cap2 >> frame2;
        imshow("Video0", frame0);
        imshow("Video1", frame1);
        imshow("Video2", frame2);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All cameras are recognized:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0  1月 14 09:05 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1  1月 14 09:30 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2  1月 14 10:11 /dev/video2
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea how to make multiple video captures happen?

Comment: You want to search StackOverflow on USB bandwidth limitation for multiple USB webcam  capture simultaneously. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282473/868014

Comment: Roman R. No, it is not about USB bandwidth limitation.

Comment: Maybe try opening them in a different order to see if it is always, say, the second camera you open, or always a specific one of your three cameras.

Comment: I found that whatever the camera index I gave, it always popped up the built-in camera, say index < 100, so, simply, I only verified with the built-in camera, index = 0, it is working. I assumed the error meant that trying to open the same camera multiple times, is this a bug in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2):

The **first** thing with multiple USB cameras, and unrelated to OpenCV is the USB bandwidth, which rarely supports more than one camera bandwidth per USB port, for which it is recommended to connect each camera to a separate USB port, and NOT to a USB hub.

The **second** thing (my experience in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04; haven't tested in Windows) that some cameras will take two indexes, such that if there are two cameras, you can try opening camera index 0 for the first camera, and camera index 2 for the second:

```cpp
    VideoCapture camA(0);
    VideoCapture camB(2);
```

And third, it is good practice to control the apiPreference for the camera stream. For example, to use Linux V4L2 and remove GStreamer from the video pipeline, instead of the above use this (OpenCV must have been built selecting WITH_CAP_V4L2):

```cpp
    VideoCapture camA(0, CAP_V4L2);
    VideoCapture camB(2, CAP_V4L2);
```