# Using Directshow C# How top get live feed from multiple USB cameras in multiple windows without crashing

Tags: c#, video-capture, directshow, directshow.net

I am working on a project in C# using Directshow which mainly focuses on image processing  and printing in real time. I have written a code for capturing the images and displaying them in a output window . The code works fine with 4 cameras simultaneously.But the moment I add 5th camera the live feed from the 1st 4 cameras starts to glitch.And when I add 6th Camera the video from all the cameras stops .For my project I need to work with 16 cameras and none of them should have low performance.

I have tried to optimize the graph by making all the graphs at once and then using them for their respective cameras but even then the issue isn't resolved.

I am using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/capture) project as reference.

the Live cameras feeds should not glitch since there is more than enough memory and CPU for it to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB bandwidth is a typical problem with several USB cameras connected simultaneously. That is, it is unlikely to be a CPU or RAM issue.

- [Unable to display two cameras in DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585291/868014)
- [2 usb cameras not working with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282473/868014)
- [Implications of using many USB web cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519057/implications-of-using-many-usb-web-cameras)

I doubt you can use 16 at a time (even distributed between USB hosts) and in any event with 16 video inputs you are limited to either low resolution capture or, instead, capture of video encoded on hardware, even with a light encoding like JPEG (a lot or even majority of webcams nowadays offer on-camera M-JPEG encoding).